# How to set up multiple firebase .on() listeners and trigger function after all have resolved

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have multiple `on()` listeners set up on different nodes to get data required for generating some tables of data. After a listener updates, it regenerates all the tables on the website. The problem is that on the first webpage load, it has to regenerate the tables once for each `.on()` listener, this is excessive. I tried making each listener into a promise so that I could run `gen_tables()` only after they all resolve and it worked great, except that the listeners seem to have been called off and no longer listen. How can I have the `gen_tables()` run only once on first load, but then still have my multiple listeners continue listening?

Here is my code that works, but has to run `gen_tables()` 6 times

```
//LISTENER - CURRENT_WEEK_DATA

db.ref(`weeks/${currentweek}`).on("value", (snap) => {
  currentWeekData = snap.val();
  console.log("DOWNLOADING currentWeekData From Firebase: ", currentWeekData);
  gen_tables();
});

//LISTENER - ORDERS_PROCESSING
db.ref("orders_processing").on("value", (snap) => {
  orders_processing = snap.val();
  console.log(
    "DOWNLOADING orders_processing From Firebase: ",
    orders_processing
  );
  gen_tables();
});

//LISTENER - ORDERS_META
db.ref("orders_meta").on("value", (snap) => {
  orders_meta = snap.val();
  console.log("DOWNLOADING orders_meta From Firebase");
  gen_tables();
});

//LISTENER - ORDERS NEXT WEEK Do i neeed this?
db.ref("orders_next_week").on("value", (snap) => {
  orders_next_week = snap.val();
  console.log("orders_next_week DOWNLOADED From Firebase: ", orders_next_week);
  gen_tables();
});

//LISTENER - PRODUCTS
db.ref("products").on("value", (snap) => {
  console.log("DOWNLOADING PRODUCTS");
  products = snap.val();
  gen_tables();
});

//LISTENER -PRODUCTS_META
db.ref("products_meta").on("value", (snap) => {
  console.log("DOWNLOADING PRODUCTS_META");
  products_meta = snap.val();
  gen_tables();
});
```

and here is the code with the Promise.all method to wait until all  `.on()` have resolved to run `gen_tables()` only once, but doesn't continue listening after first load:

```
const listener = (ref) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const onError = (error) => reject(error);
    const onData = (snap) => resolve(snap.val());

    db.ref(ref).on("value", onData, onError);
  });
};

let listeners = [
  listener("orders_meta"),
  listener("orders_next_week"),
  listener("orders_processing"),
  listener("products"),
  listener("products_meta"),
  listener(`weeks/${currentweek}`),
];

Promise.all(listeners).then(function (values) {
  console.log(values);
  orders_meta = values[0];
  orders_next_week = values[1];
  orders_processing = values[2];
  products = values[3];
  products_meta = values[4];
  currentWeekData = values[5];
  gen_tables();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You should rethink your architecture.  Since you're not passing any values to `gen_tables()` I'm assuming it updates *all* tables, is that correct?  In that case why not set up a Cloud Function that's triggered by Cloud Scheduler every *n* minutes to execute `gen_tables()`?

If you want to only call `gen_tables()` if an update has occurred, use your .on() listeners to set a value in your database to `1` when a write happens and when your Cloud Function executes it only calls `gen_tables()` if that value is 1.

If you want more nuanced updates, use your `.on()` listeners to update a queue with the table name to update and then have a Cloud Scheduler-triggered Cloud Function check every *n* minutes for updates and process those.

Comment: I am passing information to gen_tables(), but simply via setting a global variable with the new information and then the gen_tables() uses those global variables.
I'm using realtime database intentionally, I need the table to update when a piece of data is edited. gen_tables() will be called a hundred times in a session.

Comment: The issue is that your approach introduces a serious race condition.  Let's say two separate users are updating the RTDB simultaneously.  It may run gen_tables() when half of the updates are from user 1 and the other half from user 2 and it may run gen_tables before the update has fully propagated.  The above recommendation or even better queuing architecture might be preferred if scale is a requirement. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the thought-provoking perspective as I am new to programming. However, isn’t this architectural issue besides the point of the question? Isn’t it relatively common to calculate something only after receiving data from two different sources yet also continue to listen for changes? I don’t know what I don’t know :)